# Is there a way to disable Servo metrics?

Tags: spring-cloud

We do not use exposed Servo metrics and I would like to disable them.

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by an explicit property. If servo isn't on the classpath, it won't auto-configure, but I suspect the netflix packages won't like that. Create an issue for disabling servo metrics explicitly if you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Try *spring.metrics.servo.enabled=false* in properties file